# VirtualBox Guest Additions for Fedora 11

Tags: virtualbox, fedora, fedora-11

I have Fedora 11 on a VirtualBox.
I installed the Guest Additions package following these instructions: http://www.toadz.dk/2009/07/installing-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora-11-in-windows/

It works fine, until I do a System > Administration > Software Update. After the reboot, the guest additions don't work anymore (the resolution is not nice, the cursor does not automatically follows, the shared folders won't work, ...).

I have to re-do the guest addition install every time I do an update (and reboot).

Is that normal? What Can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a live CD or a full install on VirtualBox ?

Comment: full install fedora 11

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing (via YUM) the [dynamic kernel module support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) package, which should automatically rebuild your kernel modules. If that doesn't work, you'll need to re-install the VBox guest additions whenever you update the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the Guest Additions build several modules during their installation (e.g. the shared folder module). Modules are tight to the Kernel version you're running (e.g. 2.6.31) so whenever this changes you have to *install* the Guest Additions again.

Answering your question it is normal if the Kernel version was updated, you won't have to do it whenever you update your system, just when the Kernel gets updated.